# div is too short -- clearfix doesn't work but my elements aren't floated

Tags: html, css

I'm using the html5 boilerplate clearfix on my .content div on my site. But on two pages, where the contents of the .content div are actually longer than the min-height I gave it, they get chopped off. But clearfix generally helps fix problems caused by floated element within a parent div. But my .cell divs are not floated.

```
<div class="content clearfix">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    //etc
</div>




//css
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {    
 content: " "; /* 1 */
display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cleafix:after {
    clear: both;
}
.cell {
box-shadow: 5px 3px 5px #ccc;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 1.25em;
margin: 15px 10px;
min-height: 250px;
vertical-align: top;
width: 365px;
}

.content {
border-left: 1px dotted #eee;
float: right;
height: 100%;
margin-bottom: 100px;
margin-left: 10px;
overflow: visible;
padding-left: 15px;
text-align: center;
width: 779px;
}
```

Comment: It's the `height: 100%` that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is because the height of `.content` is relative to the parent's height which is relative to the height of the window.

Therefore the height of the child, `.content`, will never extend past this as it is constrained by the parent element. Remove the following:

```
.content {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested it in the new html file and height: 100% is not the issue. May be if you want to float your cell, just add float: left; in cell class.